# How can I pass variable in script via terminal when execute abc.sh

Tags: shell-script, environment-variables

I want to pass variable in script at the time of execution

ex: `sh abc.sh export id=3`

Answer (score 10):

Exported variables and those set on the same command line are visible to the program:

```
$ cat foo.sh
#!/bin/sh
echo "$foo"

$ foo=bar ./foo.sh
bar

$ export foo=bar
$ ./foo.sh
bar
```

But a more common idiom would be to use command line arguments, they get set to the positional parameters `$1`, `$2`, etc.

```
$ cat arg.sh
#!/bin/sh
echo "$1 and $2"

$ ./arg.sh alpha beta
alpha and beta
```

Or use `"$@"` to get all command line arguments, possibly after using `shift` to remove some fixed ones from the start. For named arguments,
 it's probably better to use `getopt` ([man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/getopt.1.html)), or `getopts` ([POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/getopts.html), [tutorial in bash-hackers.org](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/getopts_tutorial)).

In any case, a robust script would have to deal with the case that some of the variables are missing (unset).

Comment: Typo in second script block: `cat > arg.sh` would overwrite arg.sh, so it has to be `cat arg.sh`. Can't edit because it is less than 6 chars, you have to do ...

Answer (score 6):

You can do this (only for this execution) on this way:

```
id=3 sh abc.sh
```

Answer (score 4):

declare (or export, not necessarey here) before execution:

```
id=3 ./myScript.sh
```

myScript.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "id = $id"
```

Output:

```
id = 3
```